# Zend View Script Errors

Tags: zend-framework

i recently moved my zend framework project to another computer, the project was working perfectly fine, however now almost all the view scripts generate parse errors. Is ai a configuration that am missing

Comment: Need more information. What kind of errors etc. Post some stack traces for example.

Comment: Also, from what type of computer did you move from and to? Case sensitivity is a factor with certain operating systems.

Answer (score 0):

At a guess, I'd say you're using short open tags in your views

```
<?= $foo ?>
```

and your new server does not have this syntax enabled.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag

Comment: i think ZF translates this to full PHP Tags if disabled.